# Inserted figure appears centered in the page

Tags: floats

The following is a paragraph in my document, but the figure appears centered in the page. Please help me.

```
Góc này cũng chính là góc giữa hai bán kính đi qua giao điểm của hai đường tròn.\\
Trường hợp đặc biệt, khi góc giữa hai \dtr là góc vuông, lúc này ta gọi hai \dtr là \textbf{trực giao.}
Khi hai \dtr trực giao, thì tiếp tuyến của đường tròn này tại điểm chung lại đi qua tâm \dtr kia.
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale = 1]{h_4}
\caption{}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please describe you problem a bit more, you are using a floating figure, LaTeX chooses the best place to put it.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question, but if you don't want your image to be centered, remove `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the position of a floating figure, the *placement specifier* should be configured. The *placement specifier* is the `[!ht]` that you have after `\begin{figure}`. Overriding this parameter defines the behavior of float placement. This includes other floats like tables as well. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures. For putting a figure exactly where it is in the LaTeX code, use `[H]` or `[h!]`. These require `\usepackage{float}`.

In addition, using `\centering` rather than the `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` environment within a `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` environment is more correct and clean. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{h_4}
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{fig:some_label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)